# MS Teams - Task Module not opening SharePoint URL

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, microsoft365

I have been trying to open SharePoint's sharing dialog using `microsoftTeams.tasks.startTask()` in my MS Teams application and it shows an infinite loader in desktop client.
As I have come across certain articles and open threads, MS Teams does support redirecting within an iframe. Opening SharePoint's sharing URL goes through the authentication first (internal redirecting using `login.microsoftonline.com`)

Things I have tried so far -

```
var currentTeamsSiteUrl = new URL(currentItem['teamSiteUrl']);
var sharingDialogUrl = `${currentTeamsSiteUrl.href}/_layouts/15/sharedialog.aspx?listId=${currentItem['ListID']}&listItemId=${currentItem['ItemID']}&clientId=sharePoint`;
var src = `${currentTeamsSiteUrl.href}/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?spfx=true&dest=${encodeURIComponent(sharingDialogUrl)}`;
                
                microsoftTeams.tasks.startTask({
                    title: "Share Item",
                    height: 560,
                    width: 350,
                    url: src,
                    fallbackUrl: null,
                    card: null,
                    completionBotId: null,
                });
```

The issue I am facing in desktop client is in attached screenshot -
[image]

Interestingly enough, the code works if I run the application in browser, and not in the MS Teams Desktop Client.

I have added `*.sharepoint.com`, `login.microsoftonline.com` as a valid domains in application config json.

I have tried opening the sharing URL using `window.open()` - opens up browser from desktop client and new tab from browser, and as per Microsoft's scholars using `Task Module` is far better approach, but that is not working in desktop client. Again, not an elegant solution.

I have been trying to find a workaround for sharing dialog not running in MS Teams desktop app and it all comes down to the error shown in the attached screenshots. I tried allowing third-party cookies for and other different solutions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/troubleshoot/teams-sign-in/sign-in-loop) to make it work but no luck so far.

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: Take a look at the X-Frame-Options header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options
The response header you are getting back from https://login.microsoftonline.com/ does not allow the browser to render it inside an <iframe> element.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft Nope, still looking for an answer.

Comment: Could you please Set the X-FRAME-OPTION response header to SAMEORIGIN.
The steps for configuring the X-Frame-Options settings are described in this article(https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Knowledge/How-to-prevent-clickjacking-with-Sitefinity)

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Thanks for your reply. However, the solution suggests to make few changes in IIS, and I do not have that. I am using MS Teams and SharePoint Online.

Comment: Alternately, set header `X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://teams.microsoft.com/`.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements)